# CSS3のアニメーションがスクロール時止まってしまう

Tags: html, css, iphone

CSS3で `transform:translate3d` などつかってアニメーションをした時
iPhoneだけスクロール時止まってしまいます。

iOS6時代でしょうか

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

この指定でなおったみたいですが、現在はダメそうです。

ちなみにAndroidだと問題なく動いています。

対応策はあるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

iOS8から改善されてたみたいです。

iOS7以下はダメみたいです。